# Parboxes generated in a for loop go off the end of my document page

Tags: xetex, loops, csv, readarray

I am a TeX novice. I am looking to typeset an arbitrary number of small (18 mm x 7 mm) labels which are produced iteratively based on alphanumeric strings stored in a CSV file. Each label should contain a QR code and its associated alphanumeric string. Using some XeLaTeX code I found online, I created a for loop which pulls alphanumeric strings from a CSV file and iteratively produces QR codes inside nice little boxes.

My issue is thus:
I can fit 14 labels on a single line in my document within the specified margins. If I include more than 14 alphanumeric codes in my CSV file, XeLaTeX simply continues the line off the end of my document page. I would like to have XeLaTeX automatically go to a new line if it reaches the right-hand margin. If I could specify the number of labels to print per line, that would also work.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} %allows for small font
\usepackage[landscape, lmargin=6mm, tmargin=5.5mm]{geometry} %small margins, landscape orientation
\usepackage{qrcode} %QR code generation
\usepackage{readarray} %reads contents of CSV file

%% Font
\setmainfont[Scale=0.5, PunctuationSpace=3, WordSpace = 0.3]{Calibri}
%Sets margins for individual labels
\renewcommand{\fboxsep}{0.2mm}
%Typesetting labels
\newcommand{\viallabel}[1]{\framebox[18mm][c]{\parbox{18mm}{\raggedright #1}}}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
%
\begin{document}
%Reads a CSV file, ports it into TeX as a macro, then iteratively creates labels using a for loop
\readarraysepchar{\\}
    \readdef{K:/QR.codes/labels.csv}\labelsmacro
    \ignoreemptyitems
    \setsepchar{\\/,}
    \readlist\mylist{\labelsmacro}
\foreachitem\x\in\mylist{\viallabel{\hspace{2mm}\qrcode[height=7mm]{\x}\hspace{1mm}{\x}}}   
\end{document}
```

Here is my CSV file:

```
MF00001
MF00002
MF00003
MF00004
MF00005
MF00006
MF00007
MF00008
MF00009
MF00010
MF00011
MF00012
MF00013
MF00014
MF00015
MF00016
MF00017
MF00018
MF00019
MF00020
```

And here is am image of the generated document:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: try `\newcommand{\viallabel}[1]{\framebox[18mm][c]{\parbox{18mm}{\raggedright #1}}\hspace{0pt}}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This worked! Thank you very much. Could you explain why this changes the output? It's not clear to me why adding 0mm space after labels forces them to wrap around the margins.

Comment: a space (even a zero space) is a potential break point for a line break, in the same way lines can be broken at the spaces between words.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see, that makes sense. If you submit this as an answer I'd be happy to accept it as best. Either way have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting lots of boxes directly behind each other. There is no break point between them and so TeX can't do a line break and will overflow.

You can insert a break point with a space (which can be zero) or a penalty.

```
\newcommand{\viallabel}[1]{\framebox[18mm][c]{\parbox{18mm}{\raggedright #1}}\hspace{0pt}}
```

It often also make sense to use \raggedright to avoid overfull lines if your boxes don't fit perfectly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach\x in {1,2,...,40}
 {\fbox{xxx!}}

\medskip 
\foreach\x in {1,2,...,40}
 {\fbox{hhh!}\hspace{0pt}}

\medskip
\foreach\x in {1,2,...,40}
 {\fbox{ppp!}\penalty0 }

\raggedright
\medskip
\foreach\x in {1,2,...,40}
 {\fbox{hhh!}\hspace{0pt}}

\medskip
\foreach\x in {1,2,...,40}
 {\fbox{ppp!}\penalty0 }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the setup (no `readarray` and some `expl3` instead):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
MF00001
MF00002
MF00003
MF00004
MF00005
MF00006
MF00007
MF00008
MF00009
MF00010
MF00011
MF00012
MF00013
MF00014
MF00015
MF00016
MF00017
MF00018
MF00019
MF00020
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} %allows for small font
\usepackage[landscape, lmargin=6mm, tmargin=5.5mm]{geometry} %small margins, landscape orientation
\usepackage{qrcode} %QR code generation

%% Font
\setmainfont[Scale=0.5, PunctuationSpace=3, WordSpace = 0.3]{Calibri}
%Sets margins for individual labels
\renewcommand{\fboxsep}{0.2mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

%Typesetting labels
\newcommand{\printlabel}[1]{%
  \framebox[18mm][l]{%
    \hspace{2mm}%
    \qrcode[height=7mm]{#1}%
    \hspace{1mm}%
    #1%
  }%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\printlabelsfromfile}{m}
 {% #1 = file name
  \yonathan_labels_print:n { #1 }
 }

\ior_new:N \g_yonathan_labels_file_ior
\seq_new:N \l_yonathan_labels_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \yonathan_labels_print:n
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g_yonathan_labels_file_ior { #1 }
  \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_yonathan_labels_file_ior
   {
    \printlabel{##1}\hspace{0pt}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\raggedright\setlength{\lineskip}{4mm}
\printlabelsfromfile{\jobname.csv}

% an example with reduced width
\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\raggedright\setlength{\lineskip}{4mm}
\printlabelsfromfile{\jobname.csv}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Change the setting of `\lineskip` to `0pt` if you want to have no gap between rows.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `\allowbreak` (which allows line breaks) at the end of your `\foreachitem` loop, in the manner of `\foreachitem\x\in\mylist{\viallabel{\hspace{2mm}\qrcode[height=7mm]{\x}\hspace{1mm}{\x}}\allowbreak}`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{labels.csv}
MF00001
MF00002
MF00003
MF00004
MF00005
MF00006
MF00007
MF00008
MF00009
MF00010
MF00011
MF00012
MF00013
MF00014
MF00015
MF00016
MF00017
MF00018
MF00019
MF00020
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} %allows for small font
\usepackage[landscape, lmargin=6mm, tmargin=5.5mm]{geometry} %small margins, landscape orientation
\usepackage{qrcode} %QR code generation
\usepackage{readarray} %reads contents of CSV file

%% Font
\setmainfont[Scale=0.5, PunctuationSpace=3, WordSpace = 0.3]{Calibri}
%Sets margins for individual labels
\renewcommand{\fboxsep}{0.2mm}
%Typesetting labels
\newcommand{\viallabel}[1]{\framebox[18mm][c]{\parbox{18mm}{\raggedright #1}}}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
%
\begin{document}
%Reads a CSV file, ports it into TeX as a macro, then iteratively creates labels using a for loop
\readarraysepchar{\\}
    \readdef{labels.csv}\labelsmacro
    \ignoreemptyitems
    \setsepchar{\\/,}
    \readlist\mylist{\labelsmacro}
\foreachitem\x\in\mylist{\viallabel{\hspace{2mm}\qrcode[height=7mm]{\x}\hspace{1mm}{\x}}\allowbreak}   
\end{document}
```

[image]